# How to connect MacBook to Socks5 proxy, but over a VPN?

Tags: macos, vpn, proxy

I have a MacBook Pro with both Mullvad VPN and Proxifier installed.

I'm trying to run both simultaneously, so that my traffic follows this pattern:

HOST >> VPN >> SOCKS5 >> Internet

Running the VPN and Proxifier simultaneously makes it impossible to access the internet. Either application works fine, but only if enabled separately.

If I try to setup the proxy in System Preferences, I learn the option is only available if Mullvad VPN is disabled.

I've achieved this on Linux using VM's, but I'd prefer to avoid VM's on the Mac.

Is installing the VPN on a travel router, connecting the Mac to the VPN router, and connecting to the Socks5 from the Mac, going to be the the least complicated solution, or would I spending money unnecessarily?

Comment: There are a number of [existing posts](https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=Vpn+proxy) about using a proxy and a vpn.  Have you explored any of these posts?

Comment: @Allan Yes, I did, not a single one of those questions is asking what I am.

Comment: @Allan It was also crossposted to InfoSec and [moved to SuperUser](https://superuser.com/q/1822037/23156) where I wrote an answer.